# Desktop not showing well using vncserver on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 14.04, gnome, 15.04, 15.10, vnc

Currently using ubuntu 15.10 on azure and installed the gnome and vnc4server latest version on ubuntu. Please find log file below:

Current VNC client screen:

[image]

```
$ cat .vnc/myhost1\:1.log   
--cut--
VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 8 (8bpp) colour-map
Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x20000c specified for    0x20000b (I        nitialization error).
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name    'org.gnome.ze        itgeist.Engine': no such name
amdxdg-su: no graphical method available for invoking '/usr/bin/amdcccle' as 'root'

$ cat .vnc/xstartup
unset SESSION_MANAGER

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus -n &
gnome-terminal &
```

How to get 24bit color with wide screen (Now I getting square screen in vnc client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply start vncserver with the command:

```
/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 :0
```

- geometry: define the resolution
- depth: define color depth

If you want to automatically start it at boot, add it into `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo cat "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 :0" >> /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: I follow above command but still same problem :<

Comment: Are you using VNC Viewer client?

Comment: If so click the Options button at the bottom of the VNC Viewer dialog and choose the Display tab and set the values you want to see if it gets effect.

Comment: yes; real vnc on windows 7

Comment: Please follow my above comment.

Comment: I set the display options but stil screen is square and i think 8bit color !!!

Comment: Make sure to enter the right session for the server address on the VNC Server box. As my start command, it should be `your_server:0`

Comment: Thanks i get 24bit color but Still screen showing square !!!

Comment: Have you tried different resolution from my sample `-geometry 1024x768`? Use the one which you think fits to your current Windows screen.

Comment: Note that you can create multiple sessions for your vnc. So you don't need to stop your current session, start a new one, eg, `/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1280 × 720 -depth 24 :1` and enter `your_server:1` in the VNC Viewer box.

Comment: Thanks to spend time with me; now i resolve all errors with you. After the set as my current windows resolution, Now i get wide sceen

Comment: Glad to know that. If possible, please mark my answer as accepted (click the check-mark next to it).